# Best practice to define a URL that is append only after running javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, tags

For example , there is an icon

e.g.

```
<img id='close' src="about:blank" />
```

The javascript function

```
$('#close').attr('src','http://abc.jpg');
```

The problem is , what is the best way to define the URL of the img tag in static html page?

Since, the current approach result in

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "about:blank".
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know the common practices in this case? Should I use src = '' or do not need to write src at all?

Comment: `about:blank` is probably not a good idea. If you're using JavaScript, why not create the _HTMLImageElement_ at run time, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Paul S. ... just inject the whole image with jQuery:

```
$(some selector in which your image can go).append('<img src="http://abc.jpg" />');
```

... or one of the several other ways jQuery has to modify the DOM:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/

Comment: By the way, if for whatever reason you don't want to do that, I'd probably just go with src="".